# how to post rating back from Jenkins to Gerrit server without using of Gerrit plugin

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I am currently using Gerrit server side hook script to trigger Jenkins job to run whenever there is a new patch set submitted to Gerrit server. I do not use Jenkins Gerrit event plugin because I do not want to have any Gerrit missed event happen.

However, I face some difficulties on how to pass the rating back to Gerrit server if the Jenkins job run successfully or fail. How can I achieve this result? Is there anyone trying to achieve the same thing as me? Please advise.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a script to vote on Gerrit using the REST API. For example, the following command will set Code-Review=1:

```
curl --request POST --user USER:PASS --data @- --header Content-Type:application/json https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/changes/CHANGE-NUMBER/revisions/PATCHSET-NUMBER/review <<EOF
{
    "message": "So far so good",
    "labels": {
        "Code-Review": 1,
    }
}
EOF
```

See more info about the REST API [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html).